# Spring 4.x OSGI support

Tags: java, spring, osgi, bundle

Does anyone knows if exists an official communication about the end of Spring Framework support to OSGi applications?

I have read some comments at unofficial posts, but I need an official answer.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by Spring support for OSGi? There are Spring OSGi bundles, there was an extension that offered support for running in an OSGi container and there was Spring DM.

Answer (score 2):

If you meant the OSGi bundles for spring 4, Apache ServiceMix continues to provide Spring OSGi bundles, they can be downloaded here:
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/servicemix/bundles/

If you meant Spring DM, it is continued by Eclipse Gemini Blueprint: https://www.eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/
Which will soon provide Spring 4 support:
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/642416/

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the Spring OSGi-ready bundles (Enterprise Bundle Repository), this the [FAQ](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/faq#q2) on their web page about its availability: frozen (no new bundles adding) but still available up until later this year. Also, EBR will transition to Eclipse.

Regarding Spring DM, this transitioned to Eclipse Virgo.
This [article on InfoQ](http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/10/spring-osgi-gradle/) summarizes pretty well the history.

Comment: Do u use Virgo in production ?